# Coded UI unable to interact with out of process Shells controls

Tags: visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests, windows-phone-8.1

I’m trying to use Coded UI on Windows Phone 8.1, to interact with the popup saying “Can {appName} record its screen and sound activity whenever it’s running?”

The popup and its children are correctly detected by the CodedUI builder and included in the UIMap as `UITestControl` with `TechnologyName = "UIA"` and `SearchProperties[ "FrameworkId" ] = "UIX"` (root window, another child window with AutomationId=PopupHost, under this there's a Button with Name = Allow).

However, all attempts to interact with those elements, be it WaitForControlExist or GetChildren, causes the test process to hang for a few minutes. After ~5 minutes of waiting the controls are usually found OK. Visual studio “Watch” window says “Function evaluation timed out”.
And attempting to Gesture.Tap a button results in another 5-10 minutes delay followed by the exception “UITestControlNotFoundException: The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties”

[MSDN blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/05/using-coded-ui-to-test-xaml-based-windows-phone-apps.aspx) says “You can also interact with Shell controls – controls that are not XAML, but essential for testing your app E2E – such as the tiles, confirmation dialogs, etc. These controls are provided by the OS and are not XAML. These will be identified as UITestControl” — it looks like such usage of CodedUI is supported and should work.

Any ideas how to fix the behavior? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft responded to [my support ticket](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/898884/coded-ui-on-wp8-1-unable-to-interact-with-some-shells-controls):

*Try disabling WaitForReady level by adding the below statement before the failing gesture call:
Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.Disabled;*

There's still 60 seconds timeout to wait, but it works.